# WTForms bringing in data from form in unicode formating

Tags: python, unicode, wtforms, flask-wtforms

For some reason WTForms is getting information in unicode format instead of the normal format. The code used to work than when it got restarted it broke.

**The error in flask view:**

> TypeError
>
> TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

**The error in console:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in **call**
>
> return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
>
> response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in 
>   handle_exception
>
> reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
>
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
>
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
>
> reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
>
> rv = self.dispatch_request()
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
>
> return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>
> File "/Users/marcellobachechi/Desktop/RMP/server.py", line 72, in hello
>
> user = form.song.data()
>
> TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

**The code is:**

```
class PickASong(Form):
    song = TextField(u'Song title', validators=[DataRequired()])

form = PickASong(csrf_enabled=False)

if form.validate_on_submit():
 user = form.song.data()
```

**The HTML**:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="login">

      <p>
          {{ form.song(size=20) }}

      <input type="submit" value="Search!"></p></p>

     {{ form.song(size=20) }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the brackets after `form.song.data` as it is already a Unicode string.

Comment: Brilliant. I have been stuck on that for 2 days now!